install ruby with asdf hangs forever
I am using asdf-ruby to install ruby 3, using chef execute.
execute 'install_ruby_with_asdf' do
    command "#{asdf} install ruby #{ruby_version}"
    action :run
    user user
    environment({ 'HOME' => deploy_dir })
    not_if "#{asdf} list ruby | grep -q #{ruby_version}"
end

This process get stuck at make -j 2 and does not move forward. If I do ctrl + c after 10-15 minutes and check in instance the ruby version is installed correctly. On checking logs I found out that make process is getting terminated because of memory issue.
ruby-build log. last few lines.
./revision.h unchanged
generating enc.mk
make: *** [uncommon.mk:863: enc.mk] Terminated

Is there any thing I can do to complete this process other than "Increasing the instance size"?
Also ruby is getting installed when command runs directly into server, without any issues.
I tried replacing chef execute with other alternatives but that didn't worked.

"Is there any thing I can do to complete this process other than 'Increasing the instance size'?" What is the current instance size? If the process has to start using swap it is going to take a long time (if it ever completes).

Add (more) swap space to the instance?

"What is the current instance size?"
I am using aws t3.small with memory(40GB)
Not using swap as of now.

Since the command succeeds when run directly, you could try adding login true property in the execute resource.

I tried login true but it doesn't works. the problem here is ruby is getting installed correctly but using chef as well but after its completed the next set of receipe code is not running. its halted.
also when checked in instance ps aux | grep chef chef process was not running.
I need to press ctrl+c to halt this and run chef client again.

PS - added swap memory of 2 GB still its getting halted
